# Swift 3 - UIPageViewController implementation returns empty (blank) view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

This seems to me like a basic question, but I have search for days and haven't been able to find an answer.

I have an empty View Controller in which I am trying to show a UIPageViewController populated with content from another VC. I have tried many ways of doing this but haven't been successful. I am following this tutorial: https://www.veasoftware.com/posts/uipageviewcontroller-in-swift-xcode-62-ios-82-tutorial, and I tried doing everything almost exactly the same as it explains. Can somebody point to what might be wrong?

By the way, my classes have their StoryboardID set correctly, and each VC is connected to its corresponding class.

Here is my Initial VC's code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

pageViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PageViewController") as? UIPageViewController

pageViewController!.dataSource = self

let startVC = self.viewControllerAt(index: 0) 
let viewControllers = NSArray(object: startVC)

pageViewController!.setViewControllers(viewControllers as! [ContentViewController], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)

self.pageViewController!.view.frame = self.view.bounds
addChildViewController(pageViewController!)
self.view.addSubview((pageViewController!.view)!)
pageViewController?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

}

    let cVC: ContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContentViewController") as! ContentViewController
    cVC.title = "Title \(index)"
    cVC.nAuthor = "Author"
    cVC.nCategory = "Sports"
    cVC.nBody = "Lorem ipsum...."
    cVC.pageIndex = index
    return cVC
}
```

This is my content class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    newsTitle.text = nTitle
    newsAuthor.text = nAuthor
    newsCategory.text = nCategory
    newsBody.text = nBody
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For future references to people with the same problem. After an arduous investigation, I saw than in swift (at least 3) I have to declare the storyboard before I call it! Might be an amateur mistake.

So before:

```
let cVC: ContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContentViewController") as! ContentViewController
```

I had to include:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
```